Livewire pagination issue
I have issues getting pagination to work in Livewire.
Livewire component:
class Products extends Component   {
   
   use WithPagination;

   public $currentRoute;

   public function mount() {
       $this->currentRoute = Route::currentRouteName();
   }

   public function render() {
       if ($this->currentRoute == 'show-category-a') {
           return view('components.products',  [
               'products_all' => Product::category_a()->paginate(12),
               'product_type' => "type1",   
           ]);
        }

        if ($this->currentRoute == 'show-category-b') {
            return view('components.products',  [
                'products_all' => Product::category_b()->paginate(12),
                'product_type' => "type2",
            ]);
        }
    }
  }

In the blade view:
<ul role="list" class="">
    @foreach($products_all as $product)
         @include('components.products.product-card', ['product' => $product])
    @endforeach
</ul>

<div class="mt-10 ">
 {{ $products_all->links() }}
</div>

In the routes file I have the following:
Route::get('/products/category_a', Products::class)->name('show-category-a');
Route::get('/products/category_b', Products::class)->name('show-category-b');

When the page loads, the products are indeed paginated per 12 and the pagination links show correctly, however when I go to the next page I get a:

404 Not Found

I can see https://url.test/products/null?page=1 whereas I would expect to see https://url.test/products/category_a?page=1
The idea of using an if statement in the render is that I only need to have one component. The pagination issue might be linked to the fact that I use if statements in the render method so if someone has a better method of achieving the same I would be open to consider.

I'm not able to reproduce your issue locally. We'd need more information to help. Have you customized your pagination views?

Yes indeed. I'm using customized pagination views. I re-published them, made minor tailwind changes and it's resolved now.
